# entity framework decimal precision - 0.0010 persisted as 0.0000

Tags: entity-framework, decimal

i have a code-first project where one of the POCOs contains a decimal field which is being setup in the database as this:

```
rate = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 4),
```

i can see in the SQL database it reflecting correct precision and scale. i need it to store scale of up to 4 digits, i.e. anything bigger than 0.0001 - however, what is happening when persisting values is - everything beyond first two digits of the scale is persisted as 0. i.e. - 0.0100 would be persisted as 0.0100 however - 0.0090, 0.0050 or 0.0010 would all be persisted as 0.0000. i am probably overlooking some obvious aspect here but i have been looking for any documentation reference and don't seem to be finding anything so far, i'd appreciate any clues on this. thank you!

Comment: You're probably looking at the wrong spot, and the error is somewhere else.

Comment: thanks Hans-Martin, at some point i was catching up on the same thought but checked the entire stack - the values were carried out correctly from the user entry to the point of context saving changes. shortly after posting this i came across this link https://storiknow.com/entity-framework-decimal-scale-and-precision-convention/ which described exactly what i was facing and it resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have found the answer here and it seems to have helped me resolve the issue. Sam talks exactly the same symptoms i was facing. re-doing steps Sam recommended seem to have resolve the issue. here is the link:

[Sam's article on the issue][1]https://storiknow.com/entity-framework-decimal-scale-and-precision-convention/

having implemented steps in Sam's article, it caused a side issue with the context creation, and i had the following errors pop-up as exception during migration add:

```
DatabaseAccess.databaseContext.ApplicationUserRole: : EntityType 'ApplicationUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

DatabaseAccess.databaseContext.ApplicationUserLogin: : EntityType 'ApplicationUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

which in my case was solved by adding the following lines to OnModelCreating():

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins").HasKey<int>(ul => ul.UserId);
```

here, the overall OnModelCreating() definition:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new decimalPrecisionAttributeConvention());


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>().ToTable("AspNetUserRoles").HasKey(ur => new { ur.RoleId, ur.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserLogin>().ToTable("AspNetUserLogins").HasKey<int>(ul => ul.UserId);           
    }
```

Just in case someone stumbles against the same issue.